# What gcloud command would list all the resources with a specific network tag?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I am reviewing firewall rules and would like to identify the specific resources for which that firewall rule applies (i.e. the resources with the specified network tag). I know this can be seen in the console by clicking on the specific firewall rule, however, I would like to do this much faster with a gcloud command.

I've reviewed the documentation [here](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/add-remove-network-tags) but I can't seem to work out the command for how to simply list the resources with a specific network tags.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The gcloud tools make this search available via the --filter command line flag. The command below will list all compute instances in GCE with the specific network tag.
DOCS: https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/topic/filters

```
gcloud compute instances list --filter="tags.items=<insert network tag>"
```

Answer (score 0):

To search across projects in GCP organization:

`gcloud asset search-all-resources --scope=organizations/<org number here> --query="networkTags:<insert network tag>"`